# Add commas into number string

Tags: python, string

I have a value running through my program that puts out a number rounded to 2 decimal places at the end, like this:

```
print ("Total cost is: ${:0.2f}".format(TotalAmount))
```

Is there a way to insert a comma value every 3 digits left of the decimal point?

e.g. `10000.00` becomes `10,000.00` or `1000000.00` becomes `1,000,000.00`.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

In Python 2.7 and 3.x, you can use the format syntax `:,`

```py
>>> total_amount = 10000
>>> print("{:,}".format(total_amount))
10,000
```

```py
>>> print("Total cost is: ${:,.2f}".format(total_amount))
Total cost is: $10,000.00
```

This is documented in [PEP 378 -- Format Specifier for Thousands Separator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/) and has an example in the [Official Docs "Using the comma as a thousands separator"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: If you're using later versions of Python, see my answer for f-strings. Cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 36):

if you are using **Python 3** or above, here is an easier way to insert a comma:

## First way

```
value = -12345672
print (format (value, ',d'))
```

## or another way

```
value = -12345672
print ('{:,}'.format(value))
```

Comment: Likely the values would be floats, not integers, so it would be `format(value, ",f")`

Answer (score 18):

You could use [`locale.currency`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.currency) if `TotalAmount` represents money. It works on Python <2.7 too:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_US.utf8'
>>> locale.currency(123456.789, symbol=False, grouping=True)
'123,456.79'
```

Note: it doesn't work with the `C` locale so you should set some other locale before calling it.

Answer (score 16):

another way very short is

```
value = -122212123.12
print(f"{value:,}")
```

Comment: A modern answer with f-strings.

Comment: how does this work? what does the colon comma do on an int?

Answer (score 8):

```
'{:20,.2f}'.format(TotalAmount)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is not particularly elegant but should work too :

```
a = "1000000.00"
e = list(a.split(".")[0])
for i in range(len(e))[::-3][1:]:
    e.insert(i+1,",")
result = "".join(e)+"."+a.split(".")[1]
```

Comment: Nice solution for an assignment.

Answer (score 5):

A function that works in python2.7+ or python3.1+

```
def comma(num):
    '''Add comma to every 3rd digit. Takes int or float and
    returns string.'''
    if type(num) == int:
        return '{:,}'.format(num)
    elif type(num) == float:
        return '{:,.2f}'.format(num) # Rounds to 2 decimal places
    else:
        print("Need int or float as input to function comma()!")
```

Answer (score 4):

Latest versions of python use f-strings. So you can do this:

```
print("Total cost: {total_amount:,}
```

As long as total_amount is a not a string. Otherwise you'd need to cast it to a number type first like so:

```
print("Total cost: {Decimal(total_amount):,}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are so much nicer than the code I was using in my (not-homework) project:

```
def commaize(number):
    text = str(number)
    parts = text.split(".")
    ret = ""
    if len(parts) > 1:
        ret = "."
        ret += parts[1] # Apparently commas aren't used to the right of the decimal point
    # The -1 offsets to len() and 0 are because len() is 1 based but text[] is 0 based
    for i in range(len(parts[0]) - 1,-1,-1):
        # We can't just check (i % 3) because we're counting from right to left
        #  and i is counting from left to right. We can overcome this by checking
        #  len() - i, although it needs to be adjusted for the off-by-one with a -1
        # We also make sure we aren't at the far-right (len() - 1) so we don't end
        #  with a comma
        if (len(parts[0]) - i - 1) % 3 == 0 and i != len(parts[0]) - 1:
            ret = "," + ret
        ret = parts[0][i] + ret
    return ret
```

Comment: "The above answers are so much nicer than the code I was using" - If existing answers are better, then there is no need to post a lower-quality answer. Additionally, this post already has an accepted answer.

Comment: At the time I was thinking it would be useful to future googlers as it didn't have the minimum Python version that some of the other answers did. Upon another review of the answers I see there already is one.

Comment: +1.  I like this.  It gives a good breakdown and gives coders the ability to port this logic easily to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Started learning Python about 5 hours ago, but I think I came up with something for integers (sorry, couldn't figure out floats). I'm in high school, so big chance the code could be way more efficient; I just made something from scratch that made sense to me. If anyone has any ideas on how to improve with ample explanation of how it works, let me know!

```
# Inserts comma separators
def place_value(num):
    perm_num = num  # Stores "num" to ensure it cannot be modified
    lis_num = list(str(num))  # Makes "num" into a list of single-character strings since lists are easier to manipulate
    if len(str(perm_num)) > 3:
        index_offset = 0  # Every time a comma is added, the numbers are all shifted over one
        for index in range(len(str(perm_num))):  # Converts "perm_num" to string so len() can count the length, then uses that for a range
            mod_index = (index + 1) % 3  # Locates every 3 index
            neg_index = -1 * (index + 1 + index_offset)  # Calculates the index that the comma will be inserted at
            if mod_index == 0:  # If "index" is evenly divisible by 3
                lis_num.insert(neg_index, ",")  # Adds comma place of negative index
                index_offset += 1  # Every time a comma is added, the index of all items in list are increased by 1 from the back
        str_num = "".join(lis_num)  # Joins list back together into string
    else:  # If the number is less than or equal to 3 digits long, don't separate with commas
        str_num = str(num)
    return str_num
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel comfortable using like this in python:

```
input_value=float(input())
print("{:,}".format(input_value))
```

Comment: Note this question was answered 9 years ago, with your answer being discussed already within the top 2 answers.