# How to add commas to digits in Python 3?

Tags: python

**How to add commas to digits in Python 3?**

```
>>> income = 50000
>>> print("Your income tax is ${0}.".format(income))
Your income tax is $50000.
```

Just wondering how to print `$50,000`?

**My question is not a duplicate**
**If I change my second line to `print("Your income tax is **${:,.2f}.".format(income))`. I am getting `$50,000.00`, but I do not want any **extra zeros after the decimal point.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180365/python-add-comma-into-number-string

Comment: I changed my code to `print("Your income tax is ${:,.2f}.".format(income))`

Comment: The output that is giving me is `$50,000.00` but I do not want the extra zeros after the decimal point.

Comment: So read about how to use `print` in python. It’s in the documentation.

Comment: Have you looked at [_What's the easiest way to add commas to an integer in Python_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909457/whats-the-easiest-way-to-add-commas-to-an-integer-in-python), it mostly applies to Python 3, too.

Comment: Too bad they don't give documentation on patience...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("Your income tax is ${:,}".format(income))
```