# Reading excel in python using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am facing issue in reading excel column using pandas library. In excel column value is described as "500,000,000.00" but when i read i get value 500000000.

how do I read exact value.
I tried converting cell value to string but it did not work for me

```
import pandas as pd  
strpath = "C:\\Deal.xls"
df=pd.read_excel(strpath,dtype=str)
header =  df.columns.tolist()
verificationData=df[header[0]].tolist()
print verificationData
```

Attaching excel snippet for reference.
[Excel file screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61hFb.png)

Comment: If you know the column name, you can try `pd.read_excel(strpath, converters={col_name: str})`

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well, to me this is the same value. Not sure what you're asking, do you want the comma separated float format on display? A string column with this format?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below given code and see if it solves your issue.

q = pd.read_excel('strpath',converters={'col_name': str})

Go through this link:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? It's the same number, just the formatting is different. Try the following if it's the formatting you're after:

```
In []: "{:,.2f}".format(round(float(500000000), 3))
Out[]: '500,000,000.00'
```

If you're asking about the formatting, this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180365/python-add-comma-into-number-string). If not, then I don't quite understand the question.